# Allow users to protect/disable their profiles

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, privacy

This is a privacy concern.  I should be able to prevent other people from viewing my profile.  A couple options that I should have...

- Only members of the site that are logged in can view my profile
- Only members with at least ____ points can view my profile
- My profile is not made public at all

Reasoning?

- I don't want random users/visitors stalking me and tracking what I do on this site
- A question/answer that I made could easily, in the future, come back to haunt me
- It's my right

At the very least, I should be able to hide certain sections of my profile.

Please consider.

Comment: what sections of your profile do you want to hide?

Comment: I am looking at your profile. Does that scare you?

Comment: @Rich B: He should be more scared that you're looking at his question. =)

Comment: @Rich B: I looked at it and then copied it to my clipboard. Now I'm printing it out on posters. Muhahahahaha!

Comment: And my profile is anonymous on here because I had to create a new login just for this meta crap.

Answer (score 14):

- I don't want random users/visitors stalking me and tracking what I do on this site
- A question/answer that I made could easily, in the future, come back to haunt me

So post anonymously.

- It's my right

No it's not.  Using the site is a privilege granted upon (very few) conditions.

- At the very least, I should be able to hide certain sections of my profile.

What sections would you want to hide?  And why would you fill in that information just to hide it?

If you don't want people finding out information about you, don't provide the information.  The site has an extremely low barrier to entry, and doesn't really require anything for you to use.  It's perfectly valid for you to use it without providing any sort of information, or using fraudulent (but not illegally obtained) information.

Comment: You heard the man. Ban him.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, despite some of the mocking comments, I think it's a fair enough question.

Obviously from a software development perspective, the thought of someone figuring out (from your questions) what you know and don't know about developing computer software might not be a major issue unless you are bluffing at work.

But if StackExchange gets off the ground and this software gets used, say, as some kind of emotional support Q&A site, then I can see privacy issues becoming quite important.

Some kind of anonymous mode might not be a bad thing to consider.

Of course, calling myself "Joe Schmoe" probably gives you a hint as to my own personal stance on privacy issues. ;)

Answer (score 4):

This is not a social networking site. If you don't want people seeing things about you, just don't put anything there.

Simple.

Answer (score 2):

I think we as a society have a really screwed up ability to differentiate between rights and privileges.

Answer (score 1):

When I look at your profile, it tells me absolutely nothing, because you didn't fill in any information. It looks like you already have your solution for privacy and anonymity.